# What other alternatives are there to Wordpress query_posts()?

Tags: wordpress, posts

The Wordpress codex says that:

> `query_posts()` is only one way amongst many to query the database and generate a list of posts. Before deciding to use query_posts(), be sure to understand the drawbacks.

but it does not list what those alternatives to `query_posts()` are. Should I be using something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this page](http://digwp.com/2011/05/loops/). It lists a few alternatives to `query_posts`. `WP_Query()` may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `get_posts()` or create a `new WP_Query`. There are a few more too that are a little more specific such as `wp_get_recent_posts()`. Have a look through `wp-includes/post.php` to see some of the available ways to get posts. I can't tell you if you should be using something else without knowing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

query_posts will update the global $wp_query. Maybe you don't want that.

If you do $my_query = new WP_Query and then $my_query->query_posts you won't mess with the globals.

Sometimes it's easier to use get_posts()

Also you have the option to make your own sql requests.